# how to prevent calling virtual function in constructor or desturctor?

Tags: c++, virtual

Some C++ materials mention we can't call a virtual function inside ctor or dtor,

(
sorry ,I think it's better to change to
Some C++ materials mention we'd better not to  call a virtual function inside ctor or dtor,

)

but we may call them accidentally. Is there any way to prevent that?

For example:

```
# include < iostream >  
using namespace std;  

class CAT  
{  
public:  
    CAT(){ f();}  
    virtual void f(){cout<<"void CAT:f()"<<std::endl;}  
};  

class SMALLCAT :public CAT  
{  
public:  
    SMALLCAT():CAT()  
    {  
    }  
    void f(){cout<<"void SMALLCAT:f()"<<std::endl;}    
};    

int main()  
{  
    SMALLCAT sc;   

}
```

output:

```
void CAT::f()  //not we expected!!!
```

Thanks

Comment: The books you read did probably suggest against it not because it is a bug but because it is confusing and causes such wrong assumptions like you posted here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to throw those "C++ materials" to the garbage bin.

You certainly *can* call virtual functions from the constructor or destructor. And they will do their job. You simply need to be aware of the language specification that clearly states that virtual dispatch mechanism works in accordance with the *current* dynamic type of the object, not with its *final* intended dynamic type. These types are not the same for an object under construction/destruction, which often confuses newbies when they attempt to invoke virtual functions from constructors/destructors. Nevertheless, calling virtual functions from constructor and destructor is useful feature of the language, as long as you know what they do and how they work in such cases. Why would you want to "prevent" it?

It is like saying that division operator is dangerous since one can divide something by zero, and asking how to "prevent" its use in the program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have add an example above , we can see that calling virtual function in ctor will cause unexpected result

Comment: @camino: That's because your expectations were incorrect and totally unfounded. What other result did you expect and, more importantly, why? For me the result you got is perfectly expected.

Comment: I read your comment again,I think I catch your meaning. BTW ,could you do me a favor to tell me where can I find the language specification about this ? many thanks!

Comment: @camino: It is confusing and you will not be last who is confused. So do not call virtual functions from constructor. AndreyT is right that it is well-defined, but it produces inelegant, unclear and hard to understand code.

Comment: Tiib, in fact what I mean is how to avoid this problem ,it can be write accidentally ,right? so if we can prevent this ,is it a good thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a virtual function inside a destructor.  Only in certain cases it won't work, and may crash your program.  The way to avoid calling them is to not call them.  There's nothing fancier I know of, other than possibly some static analysis tools to look at your code and warn you of potential problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly CAN call a virtual function inside a ctor/dtor. The issue is that your vtable is set up in each constructor (and destructor), so your virtual function call will call the implementation of the class that is currently being set up. If that's what you want, cool. But then you may as well save yourself the vtable lookup and do a scoped function call.